# problem with proof 'horoball QI extension theorem'

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

I'm reading the book of Drutu and Kapovich "Lectures on geometric group theory". In the proof of Mostow rigidity theorem, they say that they can extend an $\rho$-equivariant function $f:\Omega\to\Omega'$ with $\Omega,\Omega'$ truncated hyperbolic spaces and it's easy from the follow fact:

The homomorphism $\rho$ sends maximal abelian subgroups of $\Gamma$ to maximal abelian subgroups of $\Gamma'$ . The stabilizers of peripheral horospheres are virtually $\mathbb{Z}^{n−1}$ . Therefore, $\rho$ sends stabilizers of peripheral horospheres to stabilizers of peripheral horospheres. From this, it is immediate that peripheral horospheres map uniformly close to peripheral horospheres.

I don't know how this fact define the extension and how it proofs that the extension is quasi-isometric.
I'm following this book, theorem 22.32

https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/EPR/kapovich_drutu.pdf

Comment: To clear up a few things: In this remark they say this is how to simplify the proof that $f$ sends peripheral horospheres uniformly close to peripheral horospheres. That is the remark is about simplifying part of the horoball QI extension theorem. Do you have problems with that statement or is it with how with how it defines the extension?

Comment: If it is the later then it sounds like you actually have problems with theorem 22.19 and the theorems which it site, which is the theorem that proves the extension and qi part of your question, or misinterpreted the remark as a full argument. If the former it does not sound like that is what you are asking about in the question, so it should be edited to reflect you are not sure how "$f$ sends peripheral horospheres uniformly close to peripheral horospheres".

Comment: As a side remark, there is a more updated version which you can find [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/EPR/?C=M;O=D) under file name ggt.pdf and Mostow is theorem 22.15 in this version. (There do not seem to be any differences with what this question is concerned with from the quick look I took though)

Comment: I've modified the threat for explaining the problem. I can't see why $\rho$ sends peripheral horospheres into horospheres uniformly close and I can't see how are the steps to improve the proof.
Thank you for your time @PaulPlummer

Comment: @DonErizo: Do you understand the proof of Theorem 22.14 (ggt.pdf version)?

Comment: Yes, I understand the proof.

Comment: Then Theorem 22.14 answers all your questions.